# How do I add new column with default value in Migrator.Framework in C#?

Tags: c#, database, database-migration, migratordotnet

I am using code similar to the following:

```
 Database.AddColumn(
             "TableName",
             new Column(
                        "ColumnName",
                        DbType.String,
                        ColumnProperty.NotNull,
                        "TypeName"));
```

But I am getting error as "TypeName" is not allowed in this context, allowed context are constants, constants expression but no column name.

Comment: What is the definition of `ColumnName`? `Migrator.Framework.Column` does have a constructor which accepts `string, DbType, ColumnProperty, object`

Comment: Here ColumnName is just a string, i am getting complain on Default value which i am providing as string.

Answer (score 2):

For strings, you have to put single quotes around the default value as the `ALTER` statement is built with it directly. Try this:

```
Database.AddColumn(
         "TableName",
         new Column(
                    "ColumnName",
                    DbType.String,
                    ColumnProperty.NotNull,
                    "'TypeName'"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this way?

```
Database.AddColumn("table", new Column("colName", DbType.String, "defaultValue"));
```